# Adding all the rows from jTable to MS SQL server DB using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, swing, hibernate

I need to insert all the rows in the `jTable` to MS SQL server DB. I am using hibernate for the same. Here is the code which I had tried. If I am trying to print the `spname`, `vreq`, `vcol`, `cnname`, and `sta`, it is printing but I am unable to load these values into the DB because the loop is working only once, so it is inserting only once.

I need to load several values of `spname`, `vreq`, `vcol`, `cnname`, and `sta` to the same Labitemcode. It will be helpful if anyone help me in this issue.

```
try {
    queries();
    Login.session = Login.sessionfactory.openSession();
    Login.session.beginTransaction();
    for (int row = 0; row &lt; jTable3.getRowCount(); row++) {
        TstSpecimenPojo tsp = new TstSpecimenPojo();
        String spname = (String) jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
        String vreq = (String) jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1);
        String vcol = (String) jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2);
        String cnname = (String) jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(row, 3);
        int sta = (int) jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4);
        tsp.setLabitemcode(Labitemcode);
        tsp.setSpecimenid(spname);
        tsp.setVolreq(vreq);
        tsp.setVolcol(vcol);
        tsp.setContid(cnname);
        tsp.setTststatus(sta);
        Login.session.save(tsp);
    }
    Login.session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

**Result of printStackTrace()**

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [POJO.TstSpecimenPojo]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2638)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
    at MAIN.ServiceMapping.saveAction(ServiceMapping.java:669)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at trevahms.MainScreen.save(MainScreen.java:442)
    at trevahms.MainScreen.saveButton3Action(MainScreen.java:429)
    at trevahms.MainScreen.access$200(MainScreen.java:36)
    at trevahms.MainScreen$3.actionPerformed(MainScreen.java:92)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:386)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:33)
    ... 60 more
```

Comment: Looks like `jTable3.getRowCount()` returns 1 can you verify this.

Comment: @jens no jTable3.getRowCount() returns the number of rows that I have in my jTable

Comment: You get any exception which is not an `HibernateException`?

Comment: @jens only this is there "could not insert: [POJO.TstSpecimenPojo]"

Comment: Can you add the `e.printStacktrace` to the catch block and show the stacktrace?

Comment: @jens  Edited my question as per your request. stacktrace is added with my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Can you ale add the code for object `TstSpecimenPojo` and the create table statement for your table? And if possible the generated insert statement?

Comment: in one property you have a value that is bigger than the colunm range: `java.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation`

Comment: Thanks Jen it is working. I admit the mistake.

Comment: You can delete or [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer Overflow of an Identity Seed value may cause to this problem.

There are three **quick** solutions for this case:

1-)**You can alter** your table with:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN id_column_name bigint
```

2-)If Identity Seed is large but some id value ranges are not exists **you can Re-Seed** to 1 or any other empty seed range:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table_name', RESEED, 1)
```

3-) In management Studio, right click to the table, then follow script table as->create to->New Query Editor Window

Change the "int" type to "bigint" for your ID column. Keep this **create new table** command in the window. Then **rename your table**, finally execute your create table command that we just kept. Then **you can move your data** from your old (renamed) table into your new table( I recommend SSIS packages, import data feature to move huge datas)